# Как сохранить состояние кнопки c помощью UserDefaults в Swift?

Tags: swift, uitableview, nsuserdefaults

У меня есть контроллер с TableView в методе didSelectRowAt() происходит переход на другой контроллер. В этом контроллере находиться кнопка, которая по нажатию меняет свое изображение. Как сделать так, чтобы состояние кнопки сохранялось в зависимости от того, в какой ячейке была нажата кнопка?

Буду признателен за любую помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Передай значение свойства `isSave` в конструктор или свойство класса при инициализации контроллера `ArticleViewController`, и примени это значение вместо значения по умолч. в методе `viewDidLoad()`:

```
let articleViewController = ArticleViewController(isSave: false)
```

или

```
let articleViewController = ArticleViewController()
articleViewController.isSave = false
```

Ещё способ - это сохранять состояние кнопки в локальной переменной, используя `UserDefaults`.

Сохрани состояние кнопки в `UserDefaults` при нажатии на нее:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(self.isSave, forKey: "isSave")
```

Получай сохр. состояние кнопки из `UserDefaults` в методе `viewDidLoad()`:

```
let savedIsSave = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isSave")
```

Используйте сохр.сост. кнопки вместо значения по умолч.в методе `updateRighBarButton()`:

```
private func updateRighBarButton(isSave: Bool) {
    //...
    if isSave {
        btnSave.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "bookmark"), for: .normal)
    } else {
        btnSave.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "bookmark.fill"), for: .normal)
    }
    //...
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let savedIsSave = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isSave")
    self.updateRighBarButton(isSave: savedIsSave)
}
```

Comment: Увы, но ваш код сохраняет состояние для всех кнопок сразу. Я нажимаю кнопку в одной ячейке, а состояние кнопки меняется во всех ячейках. А мне нужно чтобы кнопка менялась лишь в той ячейке, в которой была нажата кнопка

Answer (score 0):

По хорошему в MedecineViewController добавляется массив с моделями для ArticleViewController

```
class ArticleModel {
 var text: String
 var chapterText: String
 var isSave: Bool
}
```

в ArticleViewController создается метод configure(model: ArticleModel) {}
в котором мы сохраняем модель и инициализируем текстовые поля
Когда нам будет нужно поменять состояние для картинки, просто обратимся articleModel.isSave
и если мы теперь вернемся к MedecineViewController, то состояние isSave в массиве ArticleViewController будет актуальным тк класс модели передается по ссылке а не по значению